# First GoogleMaps marker doesn't show, but the second one does

Tags: android, google-maps

The marker has an icon property and it contains a bitmap of the user's Facebook profile picture. 
I'm not really sure why the first marker doesn't load. But if you post a second, third or 4th (etc...) it works completely fine!

I don't have any other markers being added in my code other than the block of code below.

**EDIT:** This is important. The 'bitmap' value seems to be null on the first try. So it seems the if statement with the condition 'bitmap!=null' is catching it and preventing it from posting the first marker...

```
static Bitmap bitmap = null;
private Target loadtarget;
globalMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            vibe.vibrate(100);
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                    .title("New Marker");
            Log.e("TAG", accessToken.getUserId());

            String imageURL = new String("https://graph.facebook.com/" + accessToken.getUserId() + "/picture?type=small");
            loadBitmap(imageURL);

            if(bitmap!=null) {
                globalMap.addMarker(marker
                        .position(point)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 1));
            }

        }
    });
}

public void loadBitmap(String url) {
    if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            // do something with the Bitmap
            handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        }

    };

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(loadtarget);
}

public void handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    bitmap = b;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `bitmap` will be null on the first long click because there's no time to load bitmap. You are calling load() and immediately after that trying to show bitmap.

You can load bitmap not in the long click listener but before, may be in the same place of code where you're setting that listener.

```
String imageURL = new String("https://graph.facebook.com/" + accessToken.getUserId() + "/picture?type=small");
loadBitmap(imageURL);

globalMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(
    // ...
    // the same code without imageURL initialization and bitmap loading
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback)

```
static Bitmap bitmap = null;
private Target loadtarget;

 globalMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {

            globalMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            vibe.vibrate(100); 
            AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(); 
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude))
                    .title("New Marker");
            Log.e("TAG", accessToken.getUserId());

            String imageURL = new String("https://graph.facebook.com/" + accessToken.getUserId() + "/picture?type=small");
            loadBitmap(imageURL);

            if(bitmap!=null) {
                globalMap.addMarker(marker
                        .position(point)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap))
                        .anchor(0.5f, 1));
            } 

        } 
    }); 
        }
    });



    public void loadBitmap(String url) {
    if (loadtarget == null) loadtarget = new Target() {
        @Override 
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            // do something with the Bitmap 
            handleLoadedBitmap(bitmap);
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

        } 

    }; 

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).into(loadtarget);
} 

public void handleLoadedBitmap(Bitmap b) {
    bitmap = b;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed, it's still skipping the first marker.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why it wasn't posting on the first try. It's because I was calling my method loadBitmap(..) too late, I felt like the process of it retrieving the image and loading it into the target value was too long for the clickListener which instantly places the marker. I just assumed that so I called it earlier, in my method onMapReady(), and that did the job.